Перенаправление для Wireguard
Есть два сервера Wireguard 1 и Wireguard 2, и есть потребность по недоступности первого отправлять трафик клиента на второй. Как это сделать? Переписывать DNS записи увы не вариант, так как резолвинг происходит только при подключении, далее сессия просто висит на полученном ранее IP.
